# How to create an entry

Tags: entries, entry, entries-field

I come from a Node/React/Angular background and am entirely new to CMSs and for the life of me can't figure out how to post an entry.

I'm on the Entries page, and have one that I can edit, but how do I add more?

[image]

I've added sections with field, as you can see below, but where do I get to the point where I can actually add the things in?

I know this question is super-beginner and probably entirely obvious, but Craft's documentation is pretty horrible and I'm not going to pay the $40 for instructions that should be free.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what the $40 comment refers to, but the basics of all this is, I believe, quite adequately documented here:  https://craftcms.com/docs/sections-and-entries ... just for future reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your screenshot, it looks like you've added a [Single section](https://craftcms.com/docs/sections-and-entries#section-types), which by definition, there will only be one "entry" in.  Since there aren't any other types of sections, you don't have a "New Entry" button in the upper right of the entry index page.

If you want to create sections that you can create multiple entries in, you'll need to create either a Channel or Structured Section (under Settings->Sections in the Control Panel).  The difference between those is that the latter allows you to assign order and and hierarchy to the entries in them.